# Clock skew assertion

Tags: system-verilog, assertions, system-verilog-assertions

Is it possible to have absolute delays specified in Sequences for assertions as shown below:

```
sequence Sab
 a # 2ns b;
endsequence
```

This doesn't compile for sure. But I just wanted to know how to go about such situations when we want to write assertions for delays not in terms of clock cycles?

Eg: I want to write an assertion to check the skew relationship between 2 clocks? How do I specify an assertion to fire when the skew exceeds say 5 ps?

Answer (score 1):

You use timing checks like $skew. See Section 31 of the [IEEE Std 1800-2012](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) [LRM](http://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf)